# vimeo api couldnot be loaded, please check and renew ssl certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate

I use slider rev plugin and use video layer, when I use vimeo first, it play normal and one day it play error, Say this message that vimeo api could not be loaded, please check and renew ssl certificate, same to youtube api, I haven't register silder rev, I'm not sure whether related with it., who can provide some suggestions, how do I fix it.